# How to create sequential ID number when using SELECT * INTO

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a complex stored procedure that is collecting data from many tables and inserting it into `MyTable`. It inserts over 1.5 M records.

What would be the most efficient way to create sequential `ID` number when populating `MyTable`

The structure of the table looks like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('MyTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE MyTable;

SELECT * 
INTO MyTable 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         col1, col2, col3
     FROM   
         Table1 
     INNER JOIN 
         Table2 ON...
     INNER JOIN 
         Table3 ON...
     INNER JOIN 
         Table4 ON...
     WHERE  
         Condition1,
         Condition2) T
```

Comment: look at the Row Number function

Comment: can any column have the identity attribute?

Comment: there are no unique records in this table

Comment: What version of sql - you have more options as you go up.

Comment: sql server 2012

Comment: Might there be rows in `MyTable` before the query starts or can the sequential identification always start at `1`?

Comment: why can't you pre create MyTable with identity column ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ID = IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1),* INTO MyTable FROM (

                            SELECT 
                                    col1,
                                    col2,
                                    col3
                            FROM    Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON...
                                    Table3 INNER JOIN Table4 ON...
                            WHERE   Condition1,
                                    Condition2
                                ) T
```

`ID = IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1)` will create an identity ID that auto increments, i didnt test the code

Comment: Why would you use a subquery?

Comment: @Gabril  Thank you very much. Clear and simple. Sorry for late respond

Answer (score 2):

I think simple row_number() is helpfull as below:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('MyTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
   DROP TABLE MyTable;

SELECT * INTO MyTable FROM (
                        SELECT 
                                RowNum = Row_Number() over (order by (Select NULL)) --Instead you can generate based on any column in the table
                                col1,
                                col2,
                                col3
                        FROM    Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON...
                                Table3 INNER JOIN Table4 ON...
                        WHERE   Condition1,
                                Condition2
                            ) T
```

Comment: I recant my testimony about easier to use sequences - I've never used the `over ( order by ( select null ) )`. Pretty slick.

Answer (score 1):

As Gabri demonstrated, you can use IDENTITY with a SELECT INTO statement. This will make that column and IDENTITY column. If you don't want it to be an IDENTITY column you can use ROW_NUMBER; this will work on any SQL 2005+ system.

```
SELECT ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), * 
INTO MyTable FROM 
(
  SELECT 
          col1,
          col2,
          col3
  FROM    Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON...
          Table3 INNER JOIN Table4 ON...
  WHERE   Condition1, Condition2
) T;
```